# PowerShell running script - stearing by keyboard

Tags: powershell, keyboard

if I have started a script in the console I know I should be able 'kill' it by ctrl-c (?).
Are there other keyboard buttons that I can use to 'stear' the script?

(I don't mean the shortcuts to control the powershell ISE)

Thanks in advance,
Gooly